# vue webpack 2 autoprefixer for ie9+

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-cli

Using Vue generated from Vuecli with the webpack build. There's a lot of magic going on. What I can't figure out is how to generate the vendor prefixes needed for IE.

This was copied from github issue: https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/issues/421#issuecomment-284322065

*vue-loader.conf.js*

```
var utils = require('./utils')
var config = require('../config')
var isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
 
module.exports = {
  loaders: utils.cssLoaders({
    sourceMap: isProduction
      ? config.build.productionSourceMap
      : config.dev.cssSourceMap,
    extract: isProduction
  }),
  postcss: [
    require('postcss-import')(),
    require('autoprefixer')({
      browsers: ['ie >= 9']
    })
  ]
}
```

**Simple container component example**

*container/index.vue*

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <slot></slot>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    import './index.scss'
    export default {}
</script>
```

*container/index.scss*

```
// this is aliased in webpack.base.conf
@import "~styles/base-config";

.container {
  @include grid(); // this generates display:flex and border-box resets
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Expected *inline* output generated in the head, (but currently don't get -ms-flexbox or -webkit- prefixes )

```
<style> 
.container {
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; // not generated
   box-sizing: border-box; 
   display: -webkit-box;  // not generated
   display: -ms-flexbox; // not generated
   display: flex;
   max-width: 100%;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
</style>
```

Related:

1. [webpack2 vue-cli autoprefixer not work in js file when require scss file？](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44029235/webpack2-vue-cli-autoprefixer-not-work-in-js-file-when-require-scss-file)
2. https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/350 Just uses autoprefixer in vue-loader.conf.js with last 2 versions ( I used `browsers: ['ie >= 9']`, didn't work )
3. **Potential solution**: https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/issues/600
   However getting source map errors in the console.

Added to build/utils.js

```
// npm install postcss-loader first then edit:
...
  var postcssLoader = {
    loader : 'postcss-loader'
  }

  // generate loader string to be used with extract text plugin
  function generateLoaders (loader, loaderOptions) {
    var loaders = [cssLoader, postcssLoader]
    if (loader) {
      loaders.push({
        loader: loader + '-loader',
        options: Object.assign({}, loaderOptions, {
          sourceMap: options.sourceMap
        })
      })
    }
...
```

**Update 26-07-2017**

Added repo here: https://github.com/sidouglas/vue-js-vendor-prefixes-bug

**Update 03-08-2017**

@Chris Camaratta

```
npm ERR! fetch failed http://remote-server/artifactory/api/npm/npm-aggregator/vue/-/vue-2.4.2.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND uscavs-repo1 remote-server
npm ERR! fetch failed http://remote-server/artifactory/api/npm/npm-aggregator/vue-router/-/vue-router-2.7.0.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND uscavs-repo1 remote-server
cloneCurrentTree: WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND uscavs-repo1 remote-server
[2]  + 56232 suspended  npm i
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to take a little different tact. The source for the Vue/Webpack template is [here](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/tree/master/template). It looks quite different than what you've got posted above. In the template's config the only thing you should have to do is "use "browserslist" field in package.json" (ref [.postcssrc.js](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/blob/master/template/.postcssrc.js#L6)).

As an experiment, try:

1. Replacing your vue-loader.conf.js with [this one](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/blob/master/template/build/vue-loader.conf.js)
2. Replace build/utils.js with [this one](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/blob/master/template/build/utils.js)
3. Ensure you have a .postcssrc.js in your project's root (alongside package.json). Copy [this one](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/blob/master/template/.postcssrc.js).
4. Add a `browserlist` section to your package.json. Again,
   [sample here](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/blob/master/template/package.json#L105)

For information on BrowserList rules, [look here](https://github.com/ai/browserslist#queries)

Comment: I updated the version of vue-cli. I copied over your files edits. I have `.postcssrc.js` in the root. I added `browserlist` rule `ie 9` to package.json. No change in css output.  In related step 3 ( see original question )  the user @KagamiChan edited utils.js with post-cssloader. That _did_ have an effect, but was triggering all kinds of css map errors. Still stuck at this stage.

Comment: I can confirm that the out of the box webpack cli rules will honor the rules in package.json without having to modify utils.js. Something else is likely at fault here. Do you have a sample setup on github we can take a look at?

Comment: As per the question: i am loading the styles as per `import './index.scss'`. Vendor prefix _do work_ inside vue style tags. Added repo shortly.

Comment: Wondering, if I should refactor me entire project to do it the "vue way". Could just import my scss inside of <style> tags and that would mitigate this issue completely. Will wait and see at this stage.

Comment: I built with the template defaults and your defaults. The diff is here: https://shareitdammit.com/37r4RdXi. That's what you're expecting right? If so, maybe this is an environmental problem. Which version of Node/NPM are you using? I'm at 6.10.3 / 3.10.10 for ref.

Comment: Can you make a pull request, so I can see what you've done please.

Comment: I couldn't install your project. See the update in the original question. Even though, I think I should be seeing some vendor prefixs in the dist/css files or is that something vue handles?

Comment: Sorry about that; pointed package.json at a local cache. Submitted a new PR. https://github.com/sidouglas/vue-js-vendor-prefixes-bug/pull/2